# Check if date ranges connect or have only specific rows in between

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2019

I store the employees' vacations in an SQL table as 2 columns of dates (StartDate : EndDate) along with the vacation type. I can't figure out the best approach to check for some rules, every time an employee tries to request a new vacation on the system:

1. An employee can't connect two vacations unless he/she shows up to work in between.
2. An employee can connect vacations but with a specific type.

What I tried to do is create a temp calendar table of the full-year dates, and joined the dates of the vacations like this:

| Dates | DutyState | Vacation | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Work | **True** | **A** |
| 2023-01-02 | Work | **True** | **A** |
| 2023-01-03 | Work | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-04 | **OFF** | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-05 | **OFF** | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-06 | Work | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-07 | Work | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-08 | Work | **True** | **B** |
| 2023-01-09 | **OFF** | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-10 | **OFF** | False | NULL |
| 2023-01-11 | Work | False | NULL |

To clarify the rules more:

This employee has a type **A** vacation from **1** to **2 Jan**, then he has another one on **8 Jan** of type **B**, He can request a vacation of any type other than **A** & **B** in any other work day(s) in this table (*only these 2 types has restrictions*), and also can request a vacation of types **A** or **B** only on **6 Jan**. Only workdays break the connection rule, that's why he can't request type **A** or **B** on **11 Jan** (Because only Off days in between it and the previous vacation on **8 Jan**) also he can't request **A** or **B** on **3 Jan** (another vacation on **2 Jan** connect to it). But he can request type **C** on any day. How to check for that in **SQL**?

**NOTE:** Workdays/Off count may vary. It's not always 3/2, and it's not related to Weekdays or Weekends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay, I figured it out: I eliminated the OFF days and then used a combination of LAG/LEAD in a case statement like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(Dates, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Dates ASC), Dates) = 1 
            AND LAG(vacID, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Dates ASC) <> vacID 
            AND LAG([Type], 1) OVER(ORDER BY Dates ASC) IN (A, B) 
            AND [Type] IN (A, B) 
            THEN 1 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LEAD(Dates, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Dates ASC), Dates) = 1 
            AND LEAD(vacID, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Dates ASC) <> vacID 
            AND LEAD([Type], 1) OVER(ORDER BY Dates ASC) IN (A, B) 
            AND [Type] IN (A, B) 
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS connects  
    FROM #DT_CalVac WHERE DutyState <> 'OFF';
```